# How to calculate percentage difference between two data frames with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage, calculation

I'm using `pandas`, and I perform some calculations and transformations, where I end up with two data frames that look more or less like this:

```
ID      'abc'     'def'
Total     4         5
Slow      0         0
Normal    1         2
Fast      3         3

ID      'abc'     'def'
Total     3         4
Slow      0         0
Normal    0         1
Fast      3         3
```

Now, given these two data frames, I want to generate a third data frame, that somehow returns how much percent of the first data frame the second one fulfills. Such that I Want the results to be like this:

```
ID      'abc'     'dfe'
Total   75.0%      80.0%
Slow     None      None
Normal   0.0%      50.0%
Fast    100.0%     100.0%
```

If there is a 0 in the first data frame, then in the resultant data frame we set that cell to `None` or something else. The whole idea is that at the end I will write the results to an Excel file, so I want the cells that have `None` to be empty in Excel. Any ideas how to do this in Python using `pandas`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply divide `df2` by `df1` on the columns of interest:

```
df2.loc[:,"'abc'":] = df2.loc[:,"'abc'":].div(df1.loc[:,"'abc'":]).mul(100)

     ID     'abc'  'dfe'
0   Total   75.0   80.0
1    Slow    NaN    NaN
2  Normal    0.0   50.0
3    Fast  100.0  100.0
```

---

**Update**

In order to format as specified, you can do:

```
df2.loc[:,"'abc'":] = df2.where(df2.loc[:,"'abc'":].isna(), 
                                df2.round(2).astype(str).add('%'))

      ID    'abc'   'dfe'
0   Total   75.0%   80.0%
1    Slow     NaN     NaN
2  Normal    0.0%   50.0%
3    Fast  100.0%  100.0%
```

Given that there are no decimal places, other than `.0`, `round(2)` has no effect on the displayed floats, however as soon as there is some float with more decimal places after having divided, you will see the `2` decimal positions for all floats.

Comment: This is the answer, short and simple.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns either many decimals or no decimals when written to excel. I need to always have 2 decimal places. Also, how can I include the % sign?

Comment: Updated the answer @terett

Comment: This seems to give for me `nan%` for the NaN values.

Comment: Check now @terett

Answer (score 0):

Pandas offers some possibilities for directly specifying [styling in the output excel file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel). It's limited, but fortunately for you does include a number-format option.

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[4, 5], [0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 3], [3, 3]],
    index=['Total', 'Slow', 'Normal', 'Fast', 'Fast'],
    columns=['abc', 'def'],
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[3, 4], [0, 0], [0, 1], [3, 3], [3, 3]],
    index=['Total', 'Slow', 'Normal', 'Fast', 'Fast'],
    columns=['abc', 'def'],
)

result_df = df2 / df1

# Change rows index into data column (to avoid any chance of having non-unique row index values,
# since the pandas styler can only handle unique row index)
result_df = result_df.reset_index()

# Write excel output file with number format styling applied
result_df.style.applymap(lambda _: 'number-format: 0.00%').to_excel('result.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This throws an error on my side: `ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.`

Comment: I'm using the `xlsxwriter` engine.

Comment: @terett Does the `ValueError` occur if you run the complete code example exactly as given here (i.e. including the `df1` and `df2` definition statements)?

Comment: That's because my scenario is a bit more complicated, I have edited the `index` of the data frame.

Comment: @terett The excel engine doesn't appear to make a difference. Options `engine=openpyxl` and `engine=xlsxwriter` generate identical excel files (at least when I tried).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't, but in one of my transformations that I previously do to the data frame, I somehow manipulate the index part too. So, maybe that's the reason for it.

Comment: @terett Alas, the unique-indices requirement appears to be a fundamental limitation of pandas built-in styler. A not very satisfying but functional workaround would be to always reset the rows index before applying the styler (see edited answer).